# php version 7.0.1 want to install xdebug

Tags: php, debugging

i have tried all the different things, but none of them work, need your expert advice.

Here is what I have (PHP 7.0.1, as well as the DLL plugin)

```
PHP Version 7.0.1

Build Date  Dec 16 2015 13:32:01
Compiler    MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   D:\NewPHP7\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API 20151012
PHP Extension   20151012
Zend Extension  320151012
Zend Extension Build    API320151012,TS,VC14
PHP Extension Build API20151012,TS,VC14
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zen Memory Manager  enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
```

I used "Tailored Installation Instructions", here is what it gave

```
Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC14 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.0.1
Zend API nr: 320151012
PHP API nr: 20151012
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: D:\NewPHP7\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: D:\NewPHP7\php\ext
Instructions

Download php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-7.0-vc14.dll
Move the downloaded file to D:\NewPHP7\php\ext
Edit D:\NewPHP7\php\php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = D:\NewPHP7\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-7.0-vc14.dll
Restart the webserver
```

I follwed every step that has been told and still wont wait the program runs through.

```
[XDebug]
;zend_extension = "D:\NewPHP7\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\NewPHP7\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\NewPHP7\tmp"
;zend_extension ="D:\NewPHP7\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll
;zend_extension ="D:\NewPHP7\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-5.4-vc9-nts.dll
;zend_extension_ts="D:\NewPHP7\php\ext\php_xdebug-4.4.1-2.0.5.dll"

zend_extension = D:\NewPHP7\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0rc4-7.0-vc14.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost" 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.remote_mode=req 
xdebug.idekey=default 
xdebug.remote_log="d:\tmp\xdebug\xdebug.log" 
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0 
xdebug.show_local_vars=9 
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0 
xdebug.trace_format=0 
xdebug.profiler_enable  = 1 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="d:\tmp\xdebug"
```

Need your Expert advice in resolving this. Been on this for days now.

Comment: If you run php in the command line, what do you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do take a look at the [formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make your question more readable and easier for others to understand.

Comment: Dunois -  I did not try to copy the entire phpinfo data, but if you need it I can, as I have attached the output of "Tailored Installation Instructions",which was provided by xdebug. Let me know either way of a way to get my debugging working.